# having trouble creating a modulo calculator with javascript

Tags: javascript, math, modulo

i can't figured out why my code won't work. I'm trying to create a little modulo calculator and i'm pretty new to javascript and came up with this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Modulo Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    Modulo Caculator 
    <script>
        var x = myModulo(5,3); //enter numbers here

        function myModulo(a,b) {
            return a % b
        };


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It should return 2 but i know i'm missing something somewhere, but what?

Comment: and it does return 2. What are you getting?

Comment: You have to use `x` somewhere, like with `Element.innerHTML =  x` or `InputElement.value = x`. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Javascript is mostly used for dynamic operations behind HTML, your code does the behind the scene-calculation of the modulo and returns 2. In addition to @PHPglue, you'll need to define some HTML to display the result. There are multiple examples for that here on Stack Overflow and the Interweb to quote *Jeremy Clarkson*

Comment: it does work just add **alert(x)** to see result

Answer (score 1):

All of your code is correct and should work just fine. You need to actually display the result of this using a piece of JavaScript on the page load (for example).

In short, at the moment you have the result of your JavaScript function `myModulo(5, 3)` stored in the variable x. Now you haven't actually told the browser where to display this returned integer value - or even when to call the function in the DOM.

You might want to try...

```
window.onload = function() {
    var output = document.getElementById("output");
    output.innerHTML(myModulo(5, 3));
};
```

and having a `div` or `p` element (for example) which have the `output` id - i.e. `<div id="output"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just fine. You just need to update the view with the calculation result..

Here is an example of a working Mod calculator.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Modulo Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Modulo Caculator </h1>
    <label for="dividend">Dividend</label>
    <input id="dividend">
    <label for="divisor">Divisor</label>
    <input id="divisor">
    <button id="calcBtn">Calculate</button>
    <p>Result is: <span id="result"></span></p>

    <script>
        // Your modulo function
        function myModulo(a,b) {
            return a % b;
        };

        // 
        var calcBtn = document.getElementById("calcBtn");
        var resultElement = document.getElementById("result");

        // Set onclick event to run the Mod and update the results
        calcBtn.onclick = function(){
            // Get values
            var dividend = document.getElementById("dividend").value;
            var divisor = document.getElementById("divisor").value;

            // Run Modulo function
            var modResult = myModulo(dividend, divisor);

            // Update Result
            resultElement.innerText = modResult;

        }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Explanation of this code**

1. First of all we create 2 inputs that will store the dividend and the divisor (your 'a' and 'b'), a button to trigger the calculation action and a span element to display the result.
2. Add an onclick event listener that will run each time the calculation button is clicked. This will execute a function that we define.
3. Once the calculation button is clicked, our onclick function retrieves both arguments, the dividend and the divisor, and runs your *myModulo* function.
4. After the result is returned, our onclick function displays it.

Hope this helps you understand more about JS and HTML interaction.
Good luck